# Raw, unprocessed URL with ASP.NET Routing

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I'm using ASP.NET UrlRoutingModule directly (*not through MVC*) to map certain routes to their handlers:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("products/{name}", handler));
```

Then, at request time, I'm getting the values from each route:

```
RouteData routeData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
routeData.Values.TryGetValue("name", out value);
```

Everything fine so far, I'm getting the proper values for each route. My problem is encoding: I want to get the **raw** value of a route data. Example: for the route above, if the requested URL is http://example.com/products/word%2Dword the resulted "name" is "**word-word**". What I want though is the exact value "**word%2Dword**".

I know that with ASP.NET I can get the raw unprocessed URL using Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"] but unfortunately I cannot use this here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

#### EDIT

My specific problem is that I would like to get more products in a single request using their names. I have for example the following product names: "**student,pupil**" and "**sick,ill**" (*their name contains a comma*). I'm also using a comma to separate names in the request.

I handle the encoding on the client side so the GET request looks like this: http://example.com/products/student%2Cpupil,sick%2Cill (*I'm encoding each name separately but I'm not encoding the separator*).

On the server side the "name" parameter will be automatically decoded by ASP.NET and the result is: "**student,pupil,sick,ill**" so now I don't know which is the separator. Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"] returns the URL as I want it ("**products/student%2Cpupil,sick%2Cill**") so I suppose there has to be a way to get the raw value as a route data.

Answer (score 0):

The "raw value" you're seeing isn't actually the original value, it's what was encoded to make the URL safe for the HTTP Protocol.

http://example.com/products/word%2Dword for instance started out as http://example.com/products/word-word and is turned back into word-word as it comes out of the HTTP transport layer.

If you pass it through Server.URLEncode you will get back the same encoded value (%2D instead of -) - but if you can't use Server variables, are you going to have access to the Server object?

Comment: In my case here I'm the one that does the request (not through a browser but through a REST client) and I'm in charge with the encoding. So, I want to get for example more products by name (their name being: "red-tomato" and "green-apple") and I need to separate the names with '-' like this: _http://example.com/products/red%2Dtomato-green%2Dapple_. If ASP.NET is already decoding the URL before I'm getting the route then "**name**" will be "**red-tomato-green-apple**" and I won't be able to decide which one is the separator.

Comment: Since %2D *IS* a hyphen, you're already saying red-tomato-green-apple to begin with.  Use different delimiters to delineate different concepts.  For-instance, red-tomato|green-apple

Comment: Indeed, that would be a solution but unfortunately I don't control the name of the products, they can contain any character as far as I'm concerned. So it is impossible to choose a separator as a single character.

Comment: What I want has to be possible somehow with routes because Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"] returns "**/products/red%2Ctomato,green%2Capple**" for http://example.com/red%2Ctomato,green%2Capple as opposite to Request.RawUrl for example that returns "**red,tomato,green,apple**" (_I'm using ',' instead of '-' used in the examples above_)

Comment: You may not control the products, but can you control the delimiter that separates the products?  And if Server.URLEncode would be an option otherwise, why, exactly, can't you access ServerVariables on the server side?

Comment: I can indeed control the delimiter but what should it be? It should be some character that I'm sure is not in any of the names but since the names can contain any character I'm left out of characters to be used as delimiter. A temporary but ugly solution is to use a string as delimiter (_like "**(,1d^[}**" that I'm pretty sure won't be part of any name_).

Comment: In order to use ServerVariables to get the raw URL I'll have to do the route mapping myself so I'll loose a bit of the power RouteTables.

Comment: Do you have any control over the client app?  Can't you use a tilde (~) for example and then prohibit that character from being used?  If not, then you'll need to develop your own escape sequence.  Heck you could do that with - anyway.  When you prepare your URL, before you concatenate the products, escape all hyphens to be, oh, ~||~, then go ahead and keep using the hyphen.  When you get to the server side, split on the hyphen first, then decode ~||~ back to hyphen so your products are restored.

Comment: Encoding the hyphen delimiter in the names is actually a good idea but it's still a hack (the current implementation is also using a hack). I was looking for a more elegant solution. Thank you for your help so far anyway, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Purity is all well and good, but an irrational situation can't demand a rational response.  Sometimes you just gotta hack the hack. ;)

Comment: I don't see it as being an irrational situation: as long as the data is there (_Request.ServerVariables has it_) why shouldn't I be able to get it? But yes indeed, if there is no other option a hack will do fine.

Comment: Sorry - that wasn't meant directly - the irrational/rational comment was meant metaphorically as a kind of simile to Hacking the hack.  Or is it simile/metaphor --- I can never remember.